# HTML table td alignment

Tags: html, html-table

I have three buttons inside a td element. Now all the buttons are being aligned vertically. How can I align them horizontally without using nested table.

Comment: What do you mean by "align them horizontally"?

Comment: Is your td's width broad enough to enable them to be aligned horizontally? It probably needs to have a fixed width, besides MarcAndreson's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using unordered list (UL) of list elements (LI) with horizontal alignment.

Here is an example:
http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal01.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS:

float:left for every button
clear: both in the end

Answer (score 1):

use div with property float left

```
<div style="float:left">
  button1
</div>

<div style="float:left">
  button2
</div>

<div style="float:left">
  button3
</div>
```